# I made a typo when installing an alternatives. How do I clear it?

Tags: alternatives

I accidentally typed `alternatives --install /user/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip pip /opt/anaconda/bin/pip` instead of `alternatives --install /usr/[...]` .

Now I can't set it to anything else, or I get the error:

```
failed to read link /user/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip pip /opt/anaconda/bin/pip: no such file or directory
the primary link for pip must be /user/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip
```

I get basically the same message when I try `alternatives --remove pip /user/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
update alternatives --remove pip /opt/anaconda/bin/pip
```

This will remove the bad link, then you can add the correct one.